# PHP - syntax error, unexpected 'elseif'

Tags: php

Why is this code wrong? I get an error on the line of elseif. I'm not really sure what is wrong here.. I'm pretty new at PHP.

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pos = strpos($path, '?admin=1');

if ($pos == true) {
    echo 'Yes'
} elseif ($pos == false) {
    echo 'No'
}
```

By the way the error that comes is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 18
```

Comment: missing semi-colons, exactly as the error message says

Comment: should probably be noted that strpos returns false if not found and the string position if it is found. == true should probably be rearranged to `if(!$pos){ echo 'No'; } else { echo 'Yes'; }`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about syntax error that is easy to fix by either using an IDE or googling the error message.

Comment: [**Proper use of ELSE/IF**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) <= that's a link (wink)

Comment: @KaiQing "Should"? - More like => **"must"** / cheers (*Peace*)

Comment: [**And leading by a nose is...**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18150484/1415724) (`$nose="A horse race expression";`) ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aren't you missing semicolons?

```
if ($pos == true) {
    echo 'Yes';
} elseif ($pos == false) {
    echo 'No';
}
```

Comment: Ah. I thought they didn't matter when there was only 1 line inside the if.. Stupid me. CSS has turned me wierd.

Comment: `echo substr_replace("Aren't you missing semicolons?","You are missing semi-colons.",0);`

Comment: Did you decipher my expression? ---^ - (+1) btw, cheers (*Peace*)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'Yes'
```

This line requires a semi-colon on the end. The same applies to the 'No' line as well, and all other PHP statements.

PHP is complaining about the `elseif` because it is seeing it when it is still waiting for the semi-colon from the previous line.